# Variable dictionary in Colander

Tags: python, colander

How can I validate following data structure using [colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/) library?

```
[
    {
        'bar': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'variable2': ['b', 'c'],
        'foo': ['a', 'c'],
    },
    {
        'something': ['foo', 'bar'],
    },
]
```

The problem is that these mapping can have any number of key-value pairs, and keys namespace is not restricted. I also want to make sure that each key is a string and each value is a sequence of strings.

I could use `Mapping(unknown='preserve')`, but it won't validate the types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, I don't think you can. You could get around the limitation you mentioned by [defining your own validator](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/extending.html#defining-a-new-validator):

> A validator is a callable which accepts two positional arguments: `node` and `value`. It returns `None` if the value is valid. It raises a `colander.Invalid` exception if the value is not valid.

Comment: Do you have a working example for the specific case of @Mikolaj Siedlarek?

Answer (score 1):

I did that but it doesn't seams to work:

```
class PolicyValidator(SchemaNode):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PolicyValidator, self).__init__(
            Mapping(unknown='preserve'), validator=self.policy_range)
        # self.add(SchemaNode(Range(min=0, max=0xFFFF), name="preserved"))

    def policy_range(self, node, policy):
        for value in policy.itervalues():
            if value < 0 or value > 0xFFFF:
                raise Invalid(node, '%r is not a valid permission.' % value)
```

I find another solution:

```
class PolicyValidator(SchemaNode):
    def __init__(self, policy):
        super(PolicyValidator, self).__init__(Mapping(unknown='preserve'))
        for key in policy.iterkeys():
            self.add(SchemaNode(Int(), name=key,
                                validator=Range(min=0, max=0xFFFF)))
```

Comment: Question and answer. Because I couldn't put all the code in a comment to the first answer.

Comment: @AndrewBurnett I am glad it fixes your issue. Yes you can probably use the second one.